# Aligning Camera to Rectangle

Tags: java, graphics, camera, scale

I'm working on a game in Java, and I'm having some trouble with finding the correct camera position. I've already made a Rectangle that shows exactly where I want the camera to be, and at what scale:
[image]

However, whenever I actually try to adjust the camera so it fits with the rectangle, I get weird results. The camera goes in weird places when I get to a point where the scale isn't 1:
[image]
(The blue rectangle shouldn't be visible in the above gif, because that's where the camera's edges should be.)
Right now I have a camera class, where I set the position with:

```
x=-((leftX+Math.abs(leftX-rightX)/2)-Main.WINDOW_WIDTH/2/scale);
y=-((topY+Math.abs(topY-bottomY)/2)-Main.WINDOW_HEIGHT/2/scale);
```

Where `leftX`, `rightX`, `topY`, and `bottomY` are the topmost, rightmost, topmost, and bottommost points of the rectangle. Those two lines of code are where the problem lies. I simply need to figure out where to move the camera based on the scale.

For translating and scaling, I have this:

```
g.translate(cam.getX(), cam.getY());
g.scale(cam.scale, cam.scale);

//Render in-game objects

g.translate(-cam.getX(), -cam.getY());
g.scale(1/cam.scale,1/cam.scale);
```

What I'm asking is, how can I move the camera so that it's perfectly aligned with the rectangle?

Comment: you want the camera to follow the player ?

Comment: can u provide more code or just put your hole game in github that ur can contribute to it

Answer (score 2):

I managed to figure it out. The answer was actually extremely simple, and I was overthinking it. I just changed

```
x=-((leftX+Math.abs(leftX-rightX)/2)-Main.WINDOW_WIDTH/2/scale);
y=-((topY+Math.abs(topY-bottomY)/2)-Main.WINDOW_HEIGHT/2/scale);
```

to

```
x=-rect.x*scale;
y=-rect.y*scale;
```

where rect is that blue rectangle shown in the original post.

Comment: Glad to see that you found a solution! Don't forget to [mark it as accepted](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work/5235#5235) - it helps others who may run into the same or similar problems.